# How can I add Version info to my Console Applications?

Tags: delphi, ide, console-application, versioning

It appears to be what console application projects generated by IDE's intrinsic wizard cannot have version resource **managed by IDE** `<- note the emphasis here`.

Is there any workaround(s) for this issue? (i even ready to write an OTA wizard)

Comment: @Robert - in my opinion, a lot of people don't know this. And on the other side versioning is important for the product life cycle, bug tracking, etc...

Comment: @RBA, i second that, there is still place left for practical "recipes" (i've chosen object repository) and/or explanation what happens behind the scene (desired effect achieved before resource file creation, as result of IOTAProjectResources creation, meaning unsaved/unnamed project can have version info too). IMO, this deserves a place in the FAQ as truly hidden IDE feature

Comment: Well, is this Question Frequently Asked? It looks like this was the first time it was asked here at all.

Comment: No, this is not an hidden IDE feature, IMHO this is a bug. Vote for QC #4723, which is open since 2003 and Delphi 7, and never fixed...

Comment: @ldsandon at least - inconsistent behaviour (probebly related to the fact developers are considering console appication project as second-class, backward, or something alike). Voted it up.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add in your .dpr ( for example above the *begin* of the main code) the line:

```
{$R *.res}
```

Then build your project.

It will force a resource file (.res) to be created. This also allows you to set the version info in the project options.

Update: I noticed that this 'bug' is fixed in Delphi 10 Seattle, or maybe in an earlier version. When I create a new console application, it will automatically have that `$R` directive.